# Django and mongo really schemaless

Tags: django, database-design, mongodb, database-schema

I have to write a web app with django and mongo. I choosed mongoengine.
My db has only one collection with a lot of keys, that can change so for me defining a model like:

```
from django.db import models  


class Article(models.Model):  
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 64)  
    content = models.TextField()
```

Is really hard. And I think that if I must write a schema model like the above, it isn't a real schema less integratioon, because I have to write down all attributes.
Any hint?

Answer (score 1):

From mongoengine documentation:

> MongoDB is schemaless, which means that no schema is enforced by the database — we may add and remove fields however we want and MongoDB won’t complain. This makes life a lot easier in many regards, especially when there is a change to the data model. However, defining schemata for our documents can help to iron out bugs involving incorrect types or missing fields, and also allow us to define utility methods on our documents in the same way that traditional ORMs do.

http://readthedocs.org/docs/mongoengine-odm/en/latest/tutorial.html

My hint is use data models when you can and don't use them when you can't

Comment: OK, than? And why I can't how to do?